# how to force the page reload in primefaces?

Tags: java, javascript, primefaces

I want to force the reload of the page in my page after the download of my file.

I tried this but it did not work

```
  <p:commandButton ajax="false" actionListener="#{fileDownloadController.forceDownload}">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadController.downloadXMLFile(myBean.mostRecentFile)}" />  
    </p:commandButton> 
 </p:commandButton>
```

EDITED
      This solution correctly reloads but it happens before the file can be downloaded

```
 public StreamedContent downloadXMLFile(DMFile dmFile) {
  ...
  return new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "text/xml", fileName);
```

}

And

```
public void forceReload(){
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    try {
        ec.redirect(((HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest()).getRequestURI());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileDownloadController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
// Redirect
public static void redirect(String urlStr) 
{
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String url = ctx.getExternalContext().encodeActionURL(ctx.getApplication().getViewHandler().getActionURL(ctx, urlStr.replaceAll("\\?faces-redirect=true", "")));
    try { ctx.getExternalContext().redirect(url); }
    catch (IOException ioe) { throw new FacesException(ioe); }
}
```

or

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
ec.redirect(((HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest()).getRequestURI());
```

Comment: yes, thanks, that's exactly I was seeking, however, I cannot download any more

Comment: what does that mean, "cannot download anymore"? You get an error?

Comment: well, the refresh is done before the download can happen, because I have to put "ExternalContext ec" before the return new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "text/xml", fileName);

Comment: Hm I think I understand. You can't do a redirect AND a download in one request; those are two separate requests to be made. the only thing I can come up with is that you set some sort of flag after the download finishes and on the client side you have an ajax poll checking for that flag to be set, at which point the redirect is triggered from the client side.